# Apply GBSVolatility to each row

Tags: r, apply

I have a rather simple question but unfortunately just cannot get to a result:
I would like to apply the GBSVolatility function to each row of my data.frame.

I did the following:

```
> vol <- function(x) GBSVolatility(x$Price, "c", S = 1000, x$Strike, Time = 1/4, 
r = 0.01, b = 0.02, maxiter = 500)
> foo$iv <- apply(foo, 1, vol)
```

But this does not work. Can someone tell me why?

Thanks alot

Dani

**Update:**
Thank you for your suggestion. My data frame is called foo and looks like this

```
Date Price Strike Name
1.1  100   1200    X
1.1  120   1500    P
etc.
```

I would like to make a new column with the implied volatility. I tried to apply,

```
vol <- function(x) GBSVolatility(x["Price"], "c", S = 1000, x["Strike"], 
     Time = 1/4,  r = 0.01, b = 0.02, maxiter = 500)
foo$iv <- apply(foo, 1, vol)
```

but it didn't work as well.

Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

applying for data frame on row converts numeric to character if one or more column of the data frame is character. So easy workaround is to convert again in vol:

```
vol <- function(x) GBSVolatility(as.numeric(x["Price"]), "c", S = 1000,    
  as.numeric(x["Strike"]), Time = 1/4, r = 0.01, b = 0.02, maxiter = 500)
apply(foo, 1, vol)
```

This is not elegant.
I can not recall just now the more elegant way, probably using d*ply or something...

Probably this is more elegant:

```
library(plyr)
vol <- function(x) GBSVolatility(x$Price, "c", S = 1000, x$Strike, 
  Time = 1/4, r = 0.01, b = 0.02, maxiter = 500)
foo$iv <- adply(foo, 1, vol)$V1
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `$` since the inputs given by apply are named vectors not data.frames. So this should work:

```
vol <- function(x) GBSVolatility(x["Price"], "c", S = 1000, x["Strike"], 
         Time = 1/4,  r = 0.01, b = 0.02, maxiter = 500)
foo$iv <- apply(foo, 1, vol)
```

Comment: I think you mean "named vectors", not "matrices". if `foo` is a standard data frame, `x` will be a numeric vector with a names attribute, not a matrix.

Comment: @Gavin Good point, I have extrapolated this from more dimensional cases. I'll update the answer.

Comment: thanks very much, but unfortunately it didnt' work. To I have to write the function differently? I updated my Q.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I can do. It's a little more "magic" but also I think the most readable option so far?

```
foo <- read.table(textConnection("Date Price Strike Name
1.1  100   1200    X
1.1  120   1500    P"),header=TRUE)

foo$iv <- with(d,mapply(GBSVolatility,
              Price,Strike,
              MoreArgs=list(TypeFlag="c",S=1000,
                Time=1/4,r=0.01,b=0.02,maxiter=500)))
```